# SDK version 29 not modified after migrated the developer preview android-R

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement newer android SDK in my app with below configurations,

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 'android-R'
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0-rc4"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 'R'
    }
    ...
}
```

I need some clarification,

1. We have faced the SDK version 29 was not modified after migrated the developer preview android-R. I think the SDK version is 30 right?
2. I have compared both android 29 & android R build.prop files & SDK version is the same as 29. But in android-R build.prop file release or codename parameter is 'R'. Please confirm for us.

Comment: You wrongly tagged your question with R. R is a language per se that have nothing in common with android. Your R is a version of android